# Gazebo and PR2 simulation setup publishing nan values on base_odometry/odom

Tags: ros, gazebo, navigation, odometry, base-odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some background:
Essentially I have set up pr2 in simulation in an empty world on gazebo.

I would like to set the initial pose of the robot, so I have done the following:

```
model_state = gazebo.msg.ModelState()
model_state.model_name = 'pr2'
model_state.pose.position.x = map2lab[0]
model_state.pose.position.y = map2lab[1]

rospy.wait_for_service('/gazebo/set_model_state')
try:
    sms = rospy.ServiceProxy('/gazebo/set_model_state', SetModelState)
    print 'Model State: ' + str(model_state)
    sms(model_state)
except rospy.ServiceException, e:
    print "Service call failed: %s"%e
```

At this point, I'm not sure if it has broken yet, but I then would also like to move the robot around, so I set up the following:

```
self.pub = rospy.Publisher('/base_controller/command', Twist)
rospy.init_node('locomotionCommand')
```

Which later I use to publish something like the following (in which v and w are always real numbers):

```
twist = Twist()
twist.linear.x = v
twist.linear.y = 0
twist.linear.z = 0
twist.angular.x = 0
twist.angular.y = 0
twist.angular.z = w
self.pub.publish(twist)
```

So sometime in here, the pr2 jumps and disappears and I get the following error repeated at some high frequency:

```
[ERROR] [1343312019.823059305, 40.582000000]: TF_NAN_INPUT: Ignoring transform 
for child_frame_id "/wheelodom" from authority "default_authority" because of a 
nan value in the transform (nan nan nan) (-nan -nan -nan -nan)
```

I'm fairly certain it is only on /base_odometry/odom, here's a sample:

```
header:
  seq: 5320
  stamp:
    secs: 58
    nsecs: 971000000
  frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: ''
pose:
  pose:
    position:
      x: nan
      y: nan
      z: 0.0
    orientation:
      x: nan
      y: nan
      z: nan
      w: nan
  covariance: [4e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,     0.0, 0.0, 1.7976931348623157e+308, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,         1.7976931348623157e+308, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.7976931348623157e+308, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00028900000000000003]
twist:
  twist:
    linear:
      x: 2.2798345089
      y: 2.02649641037
      z: 0.0
    angular:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -0.20633020997
  covariance: [4e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,     0.0, 0.0, 1.7976931348623157e+308, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.7976931348623157e+308, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.7976931348623157e+308, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00028900000000000003]
```

I'm at a loss to figure out what is going on here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39896/gazebo-and-pr2-simulation-setup-publishing-nan-values-on-base_odometry/odom/) by [EmbeddedSystem](https://answers.ros.org/users/2926/embeddedsystem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2012-07-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EmbeddedSystem](https://answers.ros.org/users/2926/embeddedsystem/) on 2012-07-26**:
Other important info I forgot to mention: Ubuntu 12.04, Ros Fuerte, all up to date.

**Comment by [EmbeddedSystem](https://answers.ros.org/users/2926/embeddedsystem/) on 2012-07-26**:
I'm also getting this error: Could not transform imu message from torso_lift_link to base_footprint
But I'm not sure that is as relevant to my problem?  or maybe it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's happening is your robot model is "exploding": see [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/30993/how-to-fix-pr2_kinect_empty_world-broken-when/), [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/38774/issue-with-collision-model-in-gazebo/), and [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/38774/issue-with-collision-model-in-gazebo/) for what I mean by exploding.

Essentially, what's happening is the model (the PR2 in your case) is colliding with something (either itself or the plane since its and empty world) and the physics engine is not updating fast enough to catch the collision. The models wind up slightly inside of each other and, in an effort to fix the collision, the physics engine pushes the two models away from each other (sometimes at VERY high speeds making the mode "explode). That explains why the PR2 is disappearing. When this happens, the physics engine essentially stop working properly and causes the error message you are seeing. Try modifying your world file with the parameters defined [here](http://gazebo.willowgarage.com/wiki/sdf_physics). In particular, contact_max_correcting_vel defaults at 100 and can be lowered to a smaller value (e.g., 1) to slow down this violent collision correction. You can also update the update rate of the physics engine (iters).

---

Originally posted by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) with karma: 1173 on 2012-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2